# signal SIGABRT when navigate to other page

Tags: swift

I created some *signup* button that when a user clicks it should navigate to other page, but when I click this button in the simulator I'm getting

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` error

Here `main.storyboard:`

[image: Here]

The error is in `AppDelegate`:

[image]

If something missing in post, please let me know and I will add.

Comment: Please add relevant code. Unfortunately the error cannot be localized from the screenshot. Famous common mistakes are to forget the segue identifier or to change the (custom) class of the destination controller.

Comment: @vadian I clicked on `signup` button and draged it to the page from the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this in the past, try to change from `push` to `show`